# Open a standard link in electron from a remote web app

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, electron

My trivial first electron app is just embedding a remote webapp:

```
mainWindow.loadURL("http://<my-remote-web-app")
```

The web app is running standard JS and jQuery. When running from a browser and clicking on the "Help" link, it will open a new window on another page. Now, I need to have the same behaviour when running from the electron dektop app, but I have no luck. I can't run `shell` commands in the web app, as it is standard and doesn't load Electron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. Posting here for anybody's else need.

It is just a matter to setup a global function in a preload script, so that the web application could access it. In the main electron script (main.js, or index.js):

```
function createWindow () {
  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800, 
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: false,
        preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })
```

Create a preload.js script with this content:

```
const {shell} = require('electron')
var _process = process;
process.once('loaded', function() {
  global.goto_Link = function(linkurl){
        shell.openExternal(linkurl)
  }
});
```

you can now call the global function:

```
//
goto_Link("https://www.google.com");
//
```